# how to show recent view products on home page in magento

Tags: magento

I want to how recently viewed products on home page in magento. 
Currently I am using below code but this is now working. so please help!!

getLayout()->createBlock('reports/product_viewed')->setTemplate('reports/product_viewed.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>

Comment: Magento has default feature to show recently viewed products. You just need to make sure where you want to display and you can do that by modifying the layout

Comment: @Sid Where you are writing this code?Your home page is cms page or you are displaying the content using phtml file? Please provide more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you forget to echo?

```
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('reports/product_viewed')->setTemplate('reports/product_viewed.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

By the way if you're doing it from the CMS you need to use:

```
{{block type="reports/product_viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml"}}
```

Comment: No, I have not forget to echo. Also I have tried using above code from CMS but did'nt work.

Comment: Actualy, I just want to list of products on home which user just looked at. I mean recently viewed products on home page

Comment: @SId I have the same problem with Magento 1.9.3.3. did you find a solution?